# ObjectBox / ToMany - Is there a way to query() the absence of a relationship?

Tags: objectbox

I have two ObjectBox entities (`Attribute` and `Delivery`) that are linked by a `ToMany` relationship.

I'd like to use `Box.query` to select all `Attribute` with no linked `Delivery`.

Current code requires to fetch all objects and cycle through them, which is kinda cumbersome.

```java
List<Attribute> attrs = attributeBox.getAll();
for (Attribute attr : attrs) {
    if (attr.delivery.isEmpty()) { // ToMany relationship from Attribute to Delivery
        Timber.i("Attribute without delivery: %s", attr.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please vote or discuss in the following issue: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/677

Comment: Thanks, will do. I hadn't seen that one :-)